# golang struct attribute as nil

Tags: json, go

I have a struct as

```
type Result struct {
    Foo *string
}
```

I would like to get a json object like

{"Foo": null}

How do I achieve this ?

I have tried a few things:
approach 1:

```
var res1 *Result
json.Unmarshal(nil, &res1)
```

approach2

```
var res1 Result
res1.Foo = nil
```

I get a res1 struct with Foo as nil

Thanks for help!

Edit:
var res1 *Result -> var res1 Result

Comment: Define `Foo *string`

Comment: @BurakSerdar I have updated as `Foo *string` but still not working

Comment: "I would like to get a json object like `{"Foo": nil}`".  I'm not sure what you mean, because that's not a valid JSON object.

Comment: Are you asking how to marshal a Go value to  JSON or how to unmarshal JSON to a Go value?  https://go.dev/play/p/Dx1wy_U2_k4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic types in Go are not nillable. `string` is a basic type.

In order for `Foo` to be nillable, one solution is to make it a string pointer. That would look like this:

```
type Result struct {
    Foo *string
}
```

If you don't like `nil`, you can also add a boolean field explaining if `Foo` is present or not:

```
type Result struct {
    Foo string
    IsPresent bool // true if Foo is present. false otherwise.
}
```

But you would need to write a custom JSON deserializer for this. So just making `Foo` a pointer is what I would do.

##### Edit after question was changed to mention OP already is using `*string`:

To go from the JSON string `{ "Foo" : null }` to the `Result` Go struct listed above in my answer, the `json` package `Unmarshal` function can be used:

```
var r Result

err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{ "Foo" : null }`), &r)
if err != nil { /* ... */ }

// now f contains the desired data
```

To convert from the `Result` struct to the above JSON string, the `json` library `Marshal` function can be used:

```
var r Result // Foo will be zero'd to nil

jsonStr, err := json.Marshal(&r)
if err != nil { /* ... */ }

// now jsonStr contains `{ "Foo" : null }`
```

Here are the above two code blocks running in [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/d2vITlogzGh).

Comment: I have updated my defination

Comment: Is your desired goal to output this JSON string `{ "Foo" : null }` ? Or is the desired output a Go struct?

Comment: I would like go with json string. I have updated my question

Comment: updated the answer as well